# Coloring text in StatusStrip in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, statusstrip

I wonder how I accomplish the following in the `System.Windows.Forms.StatusStrip`

[image: what I want]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use other controls inside a Status Strip.

Answer (score 2):

```
MyStatusStripLabel.ForeColor = Color.Red
```